# Pip list raises ValueError

Tags: python, pip

I am not able to run `$ pip list` using pip 19.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip (python 3.6).

```
$ pip list
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2584, in version
    return self._version
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2691, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _version

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 176, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/list.py", line 148, in run
    self.output_package_listing(packages, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/list.py", line 205, in output_package_listing
    data, header = format_for_columns(packages, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/list.py", line 271, in format_for_columns
    row = [proj.project_name, proj.version]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2589, in version
    raise ValueError(tmpl % self.PKG_INFO, self)
ValueError: ("Missing 'Version:' header and/or METADATA file", Unknown [unknown version] (/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages))
```

I'm working on a fresh virtual machines where these commands have been run, with the final command installing something I had cloned from github.

```
apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip python3-dev
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
pip3 install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.0.0/en_core_web_sm-2.0.0.tar.gz#egg=en_core_web_sm-2.0.0
sudo -H pip3 install -e /vagrant
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different error messages when using pip install, pip list ect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54454367/different-error-messages-when-using-pip-install-pip-list-ect)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+AttributeError%3A+_version

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there are folders in my Python library that start with a hyphen, and those are causing errors. I wasn't sure what to rename them to, so I deleted them. This will probably cause me problems in the future, but it resolved the problem for this thread.

Assume that the problematic folder is named `-bad_folder`. These commands should solve it:

```
cd /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
rm -rf ./-bad_folder
```

the `./` before the name of the bad folder is important so the command line recognizes that it's a file and not an option for the command.

If anyone has a better solution than deleting the folders, please let me know.

Update: The folder I had with the leading hyphen was named `-pacy`; it appears that this was an artifact of an incomplete installation of spaCy (a Python package). I gave my VM more memory and installed it again, and the `-pacy` file wasn't there.

Answer (score -1):

The `pip` command often refers to Python version 2.

Try `pip3` instead.

Comment: I get the same error either way. I think both `pip` and `pip3` point to the same version of Python because `$ pip --version` returns `pip 19.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip (python 3.6)`.