# python can't show my installed librery packages

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pip, site-packages

```
devignesh@devignesh:~/soup$ pip list

Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2556, in version
    return self._version
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2663, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _version

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/basecommand.py", line 141, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/list.py", line 143, in run
    self.output_package_listing(packages, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/list.py", line 208, in output_package_listing
    data, header = format_for_columns(packages, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/list.py", line 274, in format_for_columns
    row = [proj.project_name, proj.version]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2561, in version
    raise ValueError(tmpl % self.PKG_INFO, self)
ValueError: ("Missing 'Version:' header and/or METADATA file", Unknown [unknown version] (/home/devignesh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages))

devignesh@devignesh:~/soup$
```

Comment: OS information please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different error messages when using pip install, pip list ect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54454367/different-error-messages-when-using-pip-install-pip-list-ect)