# pip install Missing 'Version:' header and/or METADATA file error

Tags: pip

I installed python2 and python3 via homebrew.

While installing package from pip -> `pip install redis`, it throw errors.

```
Error checking for conflicts.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2584, in version
    return self._version
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2691, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _version

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 503, in _warn_about_conflicts
    package_set, _dep_info = check_install_conflicts(to_install)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/check.py", line 108, in check_install_conflicts
    package_set, _ = create_package_set_from_installed()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/check.py", line 47, in create_package_set_from_installed
    package_set[name] = PackageDetails(dist.version, dist.requires())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2589, in version
    raise ValueError(tmpl % self.PKG_INFO, self)
ValueError: ("Missing 'Version:' header and/or METADATA file", Unknown [unknown version] (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages))
```

I tried re-install python3, it doesn't work.

Any solution here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different error messages when using pip install, pip list ect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54454367/different-error-messages-when-using-pip-install-pip-list-ect)

Comment: @phd Fixed it. Thanks!